# Rails like query return records if posted empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having an issue, if I post an empty text field for searching records using like query it started to show records:

Code is:

```
question_options = question.question_options.where("quiz_id = ? AND 
lower(option) like ?", self.quiz_id, "%#{self.answer_text.downcase}%").first
```

Output:

```
SELECT  "question_options".* FROM "question_options" WHERE 
"question_options"."question_id" = $1 AND (quiz_id = 2 AND lower(option) like 
'%%')  ORDER BY created_at asc LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is default behavior of SQL LIKE statement.If can prevent that as given below.

```
question_options = if self.answer_text.downcase.present?
  question.question_options.where("quiz_id = ? AND 
  lower(option) like ?", self.quiz_id, "%#{self.answer_text.downcase}%").first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `option <> ''` in `where`, Try this

```
where("quiz_id = ? AND lower(option) like ? AND (option <> '' OR option IS NOT NULL)", self.quiz_id, "%#{self.answer_text.downcase}%").first
```

Hope that helps!